# Not able to get complete html with Jsoup.connect

Tags: parsing, google-app-engine, youtube, jsoup, meta-tags

I have implemented a feature of showing url preview for that i need meta information of the url . I'm using JSOUP to read the HTML meta information. All of a sudden i'm facing issues with youtube url's . ex : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qszGzNoopTc. When i tried to pull meta information of the above mentioned url. I'm getting **head tag** as empty.

Here is the sample to fetch html of url.[image]

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect((String)url)
            .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36")
            .maxBodySize(0)
            .timeout(600000)
            .ignoreContentType(true).get();
```

Note : I'm trying this in JAVA & App engine environment . Till couple of days back it worked fine, Not sure what is causing this problem now.

When i tried in https://try.jsoup.org/ it is fine.

Comment: I've tried your code - looks OK to me. I've added `System.out.println(doc.head().text());` and got `How Elon Musk Spends His Time - YouTube`

Comment: Thanks for your time @TDG. I have edited my question (forgot to mention that in dev environment its working fine but in appengine environment it is not.)